# ImportError: cannot import name as_cuda_ndarray_variable

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, theano-cuda

While I am trying to call `as_cuda_ndarray_variable` function from `from theano.sandbox.cuda` that is wrote on separate `basic_ops.py`python file that is called inside the init.py file. My `python-2.7.16` and`theano-0.9.0`.

```py
from theano.sandbox.cuda import as_cuda_ndarray_variable
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name as_cuda_ndarray_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```py
from theano.sandbox.cuda import * as cuda_ndarray_variable
```

or

```py
import theano.sandbox.cuda as cuda_ndarray_variable
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried both ways but again facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the function `as_cuda_ndarray_variable` is not defined directly within the `theano.sandbox.cuda` module.  Try this instead:

```py
from theano.sandbox.cuda import basic_ops

basic_ops.as_cuda_ndarray_variable(1.0)
```

See the example here: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html

Comment: thanks for answering @jlcope but if we call diretly `from theano.sandbox.cuda import basic_ops

basic_ops.as_cuda_ndarray_variable(1.0)` but it is calling like statically. But we want dynamically. And also some process need to be happened to input before we called this function.